# How can I write this Python code in Java (parsing a string of ints, using delimiter)?

Tags: java, python, parsing

Python code:

```
str = "123;456;789"
strlist = str.split(";")
strlist = [int("%s" % s) for s in strlist]
print strlist
```

Comment: Huh? The third line should be just `strlist = [int(s) for s in strlist]`. Even better, drop it completely and change the second line to `strlist = [int(s) for s in str.split(";")]`. Finally, don't use `str` as a variable name (it overrides the built-in name `str` which you probably don't want).

Answer (score 3):

```
String str = "123;456;789";
String[] strList = str.split(";");

ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (String s : strList) {
    intList.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
}

System.out.println(intList);
```

Comment: It would be better to create the ArrayList with the right capacity: `new ArrayList<Integer>(strList.length));`

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println("[123, 456, 789]");